# titletoc-like toc-layout for subsections with KOMA-Script only

Tags: koma-script, titletoc

Since the use of `titletoc` in connection with `KOMA-Script` is not recommended, I am looking for a solution that allows the following toc-layout for subsections exclusively with `KOMA-Script`. I tried it first using `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` and `tocraggedpagenumber`, but I couldn't find a way to prevent the line break after an entry – if it can work with `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` at all. The following minimal example shows my current attempt using `titletoc`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{subsection}
  [3.8em]
  {\small\itshape}
  {\thecontentslabel\ }
  {}
  {\ \thecontentspage}
  [\ $\cdot$\ ]
  []

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Testchapter}
\section{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Many thanks in advance,
Benedikt

Comment: This is an interesting question (+1), but unfortunaly there is no style for this type of entry. Defining such a new style using `\DeclareTOCEntryStyle` (note the changed order of "Entry" and "Style") is really complex. Additionally the existing styles (eg `tocline`) must be modified too. So there is no suggestion to replace the `titletoc` solution by KOMA-Script code.

Comment: @esdd Thank you for your comment. Due to the complexity I will probably have to stay with the `titletoc` solution. Although the combination with KOMA-Script is not recommended, I haven't noticed any unintended problems so far – a complete KOMA-Script solution would just have been nice. I only replaced the version of `titletoc` currently available in TeX Live 2019 with the development version from [GitHub](https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec), because there were hyperlink problems with package `hyperref` before (see [here](https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues/3)).

Comment: Good news: Markus informed me that the next `tocbasic` version will provide a new style `toctext` - see [Geplante Änderungen in zukünftigen KOMA-Script-Versionen](https://komascript.de/releasesvn) (German).

Comment: @esdd That's really good news! I have adjusted my question...

Comment: My suggestion: ask Markus directly. You will find his e-mail in the copyright info at the beginning of his classes and packages.

Comment: Ok, I've just sent him an e-mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From version KOMA-Script 3.27.3167 it is now possible to realize the above mentioned toc-layout with the new tocstyle `toctext` (see [comment from @esdd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498729/titletoc-like-toc-layout-for-subsections-with-koma-script-only/499336#comment1260570_498729)). Here is a new working MWE (with thanks to Markus Kohm):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  raggedright=false,% don't activate ragged right
  entryformat=\textit,% The format expects the text as argument, so we prefer
                      % \textit over \itshape
  pagenumberformat={},% don't use default \normalfont for the page numbers
  onstartfirstentry=\small,% Use \small for the whole paragraph
  onstartentry={\ $\cdot$\ },% distance and centered dot between entries
  onendentry={},% do not use the default \quad after entries,
  afterpar=\normalsize,% after final par switch back to \normalsize (note:
                       % will be executed for each entry!)
]{toctext}{subsection}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Testchapter}
\section{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Prerelease 3.27.3175 is available from the [KOMA-Script website](https://komascript.de/node/1801).

Comment: @esdd Thank you for this hint!