# typeset subsection-entries in TOC as justified text in scrbook

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, justification

Typesetting a TOC is pretty straightforward, and so is customizing it. I would like to know if there is a simple way to turn this three-level TOC

[image]

into this on the subsection-entry-level:

[image]

Background: A large book may contain large sections with a huge amount of subsections. Rather than bloating the TOC that may then span many pages or leaving the subsection-entries out completely with the downside of stealing away the opportunity for the reader to get glimpse of what is going on in the book, it would be nice if one could display the subsection-entries and the corresponding pages as justified text as a compromise.

MWE to play around with (it would be good if no conflicts with KOMA-script-specific options arise):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\subsection{Third Subsection}
\subsection{Fourth Subsection}
\subsection{Fifth Subsection}
\section{Second Section}

\chapter{Third Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[onendentry={,\enskip}]{toctext}{subsection}
```

Examples:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[onendentry={,\enskip}]{toctext}{subsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\subsection{Third Subsection}
\subsection{Fourth Subsection}
\subsection{Fifth Subsection}
\section{Second Section}
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  onendentry={,\enskip},
  entrynumberformat={\def\autodot{.}}
]{toctext}{subsection}
\renewcommand\addsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{\arabic{subsection}}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\subsection{Third Subsection}
\subsection{Fourth Subsection}
\subsection{Fifth Subsection}
\section{Second Section}
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, just one line of code. I didn’t expect that.

Comment: Which length determines the interline-spacing between the justified lines of the TOC-subsection-entries in the new TOC?

Comment: It is the normal line space. You can change it by the keys `onstartfirstpage` and `afterpar`, eg. `onstartfirstentry={\linespread{1.2}\selectfont}, afterpar={\linespread{1}\selectfont}`.

Comment: Related question for reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498729/titletoc-like-toc-layout-for-subsections-with-koma-script-only/499336#499336